# Block ciphers or stream ciphers for mobile devices?

Tags: android, encryption

I would like to know, why it is better to implement block ciphers instead of implementing stream ciphers in Android?

Comment: If you consider efficiency reasons and of course of security purspective

Comment: You need to explain what are you trying to do and what ciphers/modes you are trying to compare for this to have a meaningful answer.

Comment: I know that block ciphers have different types of modes such as ECB,CBC,EFB and counter mode and they process every time the plaintext block by block.  Stream ciphers is just like you have block cipher with 1 bit each block. Is there any good documentation that compares and gives an answer to the my question(block or stream ciphers for mobile devices?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security of types of ciphers which could be more appropriate on http://security.stackexchange.com.